# The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am getting the method `onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type Fragment` Error:

**FragmentC.java:**

```
package com.example.fragment;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentC extends Fragment{

    TextView mtext;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        TextView mtext  = new TextView(getActivity());
        mtext.setText("Fragment C added. \n Click back button to go previous state");
        mtext.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        mtext.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        return mtext;
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);  <---Error occurred here

        if(position == 2)
        {
        Fragment newFrag = new FragmentC();
        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.add(R.id.fragment_container, newFrag);
        trans.addToBackStack(null);
        trans.commit();
    }
    else
    {

    }
    }
    }
```

Anybody know how to solve these.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public class FragmentC extends Fragment{` Fragment does not have that method.

`ListFragment`  has the method. So you extend `ListFragment` instead of `Fragment`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

But in your fragment you have a `TextView`. Why do you even require `onListItemClick` when you don't extend `ListFragment`?. I don't see a `ListView` either. All you have is a `TextView` and you give no other information of what you actually need.

Comment: Bro,I got a output while extending a listFragment.Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Stephen but what is that you want?

Comment: `http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Using-Fragments-to-Build-User-Interfaces-in-Android` I referred that link and try to do some tab swipeable using fragments.Main thing is to transfer some text in Tab A to Tab B.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to extends from ListFragment check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29)

```
public static class FragmentC  extends ListFragment {

   // ...
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        showDetails(position);
    }
}
```

Also you need the `@override` keyword.